# Respond with a rich message as a Slack bot

Tags: node.js, slack-api, slack

I'm working on a Node.js slack app containing a bot user. But I don't know how to respond to a user with a rich message as a bot.

**Example:**

I can respond with simple messages without problems using this code:

```
import * as SlackClient from '@slack/client';

slackBot = new SlackClient.RtmClient(bot_access_token)
slackBot.on(SlackClient.RTM_EVENTS.MESSAGE, message => {
    slackBot.sendMessage('Hello', message.channel);
});
slackBot.start();
```

But RTM API doesn't support rich messages:

> The RTM API only supports posting simple messages formatted using our default message formatting mode. It does not support attachments or other message formatting modes. To post a more complex message as a user clients can call the chat.postMessage Web API method with as_user set to true.

so I tried to use the web client to respond with rich messages and moved to this code:

```
import * as SlackClient from '@slack/client';

slackWebClient = new SlackClient.WebClient(access_token);
slackBot = new SlackClient.RtmClient(bot_access_token)
slackBot.on(SlackClient.RTM_EVENTS.MESSAGE, message => {
    slackWebClient.chat.postMessage(message.channel, 'Hello', { attachments: myAttachments });
});
slackBot.start();
```

this approach is working when I testing the bot with my account. But if an other team user writes a DM to the bot, `slackWebClient.chat.postMessage` fails with the error `error: channel_not_found`. (I also tried to add a parameter `as_user: true` - but behaviour is the same, except that messages are signed with my name instead of bot name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I created a `SlackClient.WebClient` instance with the **Bot User OAuth Access Token** instead of the **OAuth Access Token** (also with `as_user` set to true) and now it works as intended. I didn't know that the **Bot User OAuth Access Token** can be also used as a token for the Web API client.

**Working code:**

```
import * as SlackClient from '@slack/client';

slackWebClient = new SlackClient.WebClient(bot_access_token);
slackBot = new SlackClient.RtmClient(bot_access_token)
slackBot.on(SlackClient.RTM_EVENTS.MESSAGE, message => {
    slackWebClient.chat.postMessage(message.channel, 'Hello', { attachments: myAttachments, as_user: true });
});
slackBot.start();
```